# How to solve non-linear first order initial value problem?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am struggling with how to solve a non-linear first order initial value problem. A step-by-step solution would be very helpful.

The equation is:
$$x' = -x^3 + e^{-t} $$

$$x(0) = x_0$$

I need to show that for any initial point $x_0$ that $x(t)$ goes to zero as t goes to infinity

Comment: Have you tried something yourself? Where exactly is your problem with solving this example?

Comment: So far I am just stuck. I've been solving linear ODE's using the method of integrating factors, but I don't think I can apply that here

Comment: This will not have a completely symbolic solution. Please check your task description again as to what form of solution or properties of the solution is demanded

Comment: Are you sure about $x^3$ ? The is a solution for $x^2$.

Comment: The conclusion is wrong. You can use Mathematica commands $$so = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -x[t]^3 + E^-t, x[0] == 2}, x, {t, 0, 500}], Plot[x[t] /. so[[1]], {t, 0, 500}] $$ to check.